# Exception handing in a UDF : Spark 1.6

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, exception, user-defined-functions

```
   def parse_values(value: String) = {
      val values = value.split(",").map(_.trim)
      values.foldLeft(Array[(Int, Double)]()) {
        case (acc, present) =>
          val Array(k, v) = {
            present.split(",")(0).split(":") match {
              case Array(_) => Array("0", "0.0")
              case arr => arr
            }
          }
          acc :+ (k.trim.toInt, v.trim.toDouble)
      }
    }
```

What this function does is that it parses a column of string into an array of keys and values. "`50:63.25,100:58.38`" to `[[50,63.2], [100,58.38]]`. This is my UDF which creates a wrapped array of struct elements of int and Double.

```
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- _2: double (nullable = false)
```

There are cases when the input string is not correctly formatted and I get an error: `java.lang.NumberFormatException` for the input string: because "`k.trim.toInt`" is not able to cast dirty data like "`.01-4.1293`" which is one of the exception string in a huge dataset. Can anyone help me with this issue?

I would like to return an empty array or an array with `[0,0.0]` when exception occurs. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Try` class

Instead of

```
(k.trim.toInt, v.trim.toDouble)
```

Encapsulate it in a `Try` with a `getOrElse` such as:

```
(Try(k.trim.toInt).getOrElse(0), Try(v.trim.toDouble).getOrElse(0.0))
```

It will return the proper value if succeeded and the default value of your desire if failed

Quick test here:

```
val invalid: String = .01-4.1293
val valid: String = 56


Try(invalid.trim.toInt).getOrElse(0)
res19: Int = 0

Try(valid.trim.toInt).getOrElse(0)
res20: Int = 56
```

As a whole with your function:

```
import scala.util.Try

   def parse_values(value: String) = {
      val values = value.split(",").map(_.trim)
      values.foldLeft(Array[(Int, Double)]()) {
        case (acc, present) =>
          val Array(k, v) = {
            present.split(",")(0).split(":") match {
              case Array(_) => Array("0", "0.0")
              case arr => arr
            }
          }
          acc :+ (Try(k.trim.toInt).getOrElse(0), Try(v.trim.toDouble).getOrElse(0.0))
      }
    }
```

Also you can find more info about the functional error handling and the Try class [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/functional-error-handling.html)